# How to set adapter to get different object array?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i have a layout for recyclerview, but i want to try that adapter can receive multiple array object.

example

```
var array1 : Arraylist<ObjectA>
var array2 : Arraylist<ObjectB>

fun foo1(){
   recyclerview.setAdapter(MainAdapter(array1))
}

fun foo2(){
   recyclerview.setAdapter(MainAdapter(array2))
}
```

how to set `Main Adapter` to receive that different array? because the recyclerview using same layout, same list item but different data. or I should stay with using 2 different adapter?
I was using generic class adapter but I have no idea how to create generic class properly?

Comment: Creating a new adapter with a different array is exactly right. The problem might be that you are reusing the same recyclerview. You might need to also create a new recyclerview. If you need more help than this vague hint, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One adapter is enough.

```
class MainAdapter : BaseAdapter() {
    private var dataSourceA: Arraylist<ObjectA> = ArrayList()
    private var dataSourceB: Arraylist<ObjectB> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BindingHolder {
        return if (viewType == ITEM_A) {
            generateBindingHolder(R.layout.list_item_a, parent)
        } else {
            generateBindingHolder(R.layout.list_item_b, parent)
        }  
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = dataSourceA.size + dataSourceB.size

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if (position < dataSourceA.size) ITEM_A else ITEM_B
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BindingHolder, position: Int) {
        // check holder' s type
        when (holder.binding) {
            is ListItemABinding -> {
                holder.myBind(holder.binding) {
                    // add a' s listener
                }
            }
            else -> {
                holder.myBind(holder.binding) {
                    // add b' s listener
                }
            }
        }
    }


    fun setDataSourceA(data: Arraylist<ObjectA>) {
        dataSourceA = data
    }

    fun setDataSourceB(data: Arraylist<ObjectB>) {
        dataSourceB = data
    }

    ...

}
```

```
val adapter = MainAdapter()
recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter)
adapter.setDataSourceA(array1)
adapter.setDataSourceB(array2)
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

```
abstract class BaseAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseAdapter.BindingHolder>() {

    class BindingHolder(val binding: ViewDataBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun <T : ViewDataBinding> myBind(receiver: T, block: T.() -> Unit) {
            receiver.block()
            receiver.executePendingBindings()
        }
    }

    companion object {
        fun generateBindingHolder(@LayoutRes layoutRes: Int, parent: ViewGroup): BindingHolder {
            return BindingHolder(DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), layoutRes, parent, false))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will you help add a more little code, how to add onItemClickListener for both array with separated `itemClickListener`? Or anything, when I click the item it passes the `array[position]` either `ObjectA` or `ObjectB`

Comment: @Fajar Satya Sanjaya
Added.